# Save photo collage from view android

Tags: java, android, view, bitmap

I have a next view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2.5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/a1" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/a2" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/a4" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like: [image]

In this view user can edit viewing of this pictures(zoom, rotate)

I have to save edited photo collage. How I can save view with zoomed and rotaded photos? Is it possible to save edited view in bitmap to application cache?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have three bitmaps in a list. How can make a collage of them programmatically like your image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can simply take screenshot of the edited image and create a bitmap which can be saved anywhere you want

Below is the function for getting bitmap

```
public Bitmap getBitMap() {
    try {
        yourEditedPhotoCollageLayout.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(yourEditedPhotoCollageLayout.getDrawingCache());
        return bmp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and this way you can save that bitmap

```
private void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    try {
        File storageDir = createImageFile();
        String path = storageDir.toString();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.close();

        MyMediaConnectorClient client = new MyMediaConnectorClient(path);
        MediaScannerConnection scanner = new MediaScannerConnection(
                Context, client);
        client.setScanner(scanner);
        scanner.connect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("save image", "failed to save image", e);
    }
}
```